# Batch converting NAD83 Z12 to NAD83 Z13

Tags: coordinate-system, csv, software-recommendations, batch, nad83

I have a need to to convert a CSV file that was surveyed in NAD83 Zone 12 to NAD83 Zone 13 coordinates, is there an online tool that can do this for me?

Answer (score 1):

You might try the [National Geodetic Survey Coordinate Conversion and Transformation Tool (NCAT)](https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/NCAT/). It has a multi-point option and an API as well. I haven't used the API.

When using the single point option, you can override the output UTM zone in the bottom, output portion.

[image: screen capture of NCAT software showing zone override]